# How to edit the htaccess to add this rewrite rule?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to set some rewrite rules for my page. Currently I have these:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/?$ /used-details.php?id=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

The problem is that when I try to access a folder, like http://www.domain.com/admin, instead of executing the script inside the admin/index.php file it says admin.php is not found.

I thought of two workarounds but I do not know if it is possible or how to do this.

The first one is to recognize if it is a folder, and if it is, do not use the .php rule.
 The second is to write some folders that I want not to have rules on it like the folder admin and the folder new.

How can I do this?

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` means "not a folder". You could just add that to your second cond/rule. You can have multiple conditions for a rule.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn that was easy. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` means "not a folder". You could just add that to your second cond/rule. You can have multiple conditions for a rule.

So the second rule would become:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```